# Safari 12 live editing of stylesheet not working

Tags: safari

I used to be able to live edit stylesheets under Resources in the developer console in Safari but since Safari 12 was released, the changes made to stylesheets under Resources no longer takes effect.

Is it just me or is this a problem in Safari 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, there was a parse error in the stylesheet.

It used to work in Safari 11 but in Safari 12 the stylesheet with the parse error is not parsing correctly and the live editing doesn't work as expected.

Fixing the parse error resolved it.